# Creating an executable JAR file in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Do I have to always click to file/export/executable jar menu?
Is there any way to do this with one button?
(Because for example if I use netbeans and click the clean and build button it will also generate the jar file.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you go to `Export... -> Java -> JAR File`, click next to get to the second page of the wizard.  There, you can `Save the description of this JAR in the workspace`.  When the export completes, you should have a `.jardesc` file.  You can right click on this and choose `Create JAR` for a one step export.